# Would Misa get back her Shinigami Eyes?

Tags: death-note

So I was watching Death Note, and at a certain point Misa loses her Death Note, her memories, and her eyes.  What would happen, if she gets her Death Note back for some reason? - would her shinigami eyes come back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No she doesn't, this is show later in the series which going by how the question is worded, indicates that the evidence to this would be a spoiler.

> in Episode 24 when she retrieves the Death Note that Light buried as apart of his grand plan to exonerate Himself, Misa (to save himself from Rem) and to kill L.

> After Misa recovers the book her memories return, however she had forgotten L's real name which she saw back when she was at University with Light and L and so makes the eye deal again

> *"After the Task Force says goodbye to Misa, Light orders Misa to recover the other Death Note he had hidden and buried at a particular site a few months earlier. Misa goes to the site and regains her memories, while also **finding a slip to write down the true name of "Hideki Ryuga," only for her to have forgotten** (later revealed to have also been planned). Returning from the Shinigami Realm, Ryuk greets Misa, **who makes a second deal for the Shinigami Eyes in order to find out L's true identity** (and also trading a human apple for a Shinigami one, which Misa finds sandy). Misa and Ryuk then return to the headquarters and reunite with Light out front, where **Rem notices via a security camera that Misa has again halved her life**, and now has less than a month to live."*

> Source: [Revival > Synopsis (3rd Paragraph)](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Revival)

Comment: Alright, nice to know.
It seems like that i just watched that episode so it's also true what you say.
Thanks1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the anime but in the manga

> She loses her Shinigami Eyes and her death note when she gets captured by L.

> Light later gets her to touch the death note again and she makes the deal again to get the Shinigami Eyes halfing her already halfed lifespan